# Скрипт генерации gravatar

Tags: php, gravatar

Никто не встречал в сети скрипт генерации аватарки из случайной строки, типа как орнамент на Gravatar? Мне бы хотя бы знать его название, но желательно в ответе получить ссылку.

Comment: Пример аватарки еще выложите.

Comment: Пример - ваша аватарка).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как говорится, погуглил за вас :)

- [Описание Identicon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identicon).
- [Реализация на C#](http://www.puls200.de/?p=316).
- [Реализация на PHP](http://sourceforge.net/projects/identicons/).
- [Реализация на Java](https://github.com/donpark/identicon).

ЗЫ: Я ж вам намекнул, что данная картинка называется identicon.

Comment: О, спасибо). Не знал, как называется и туго понимаю намеки).

Answer (score 2):

```
echo "http://1.gravatar.com/avatar/".md5("slu4ajnaja stroka")."/?d=identicon";
```

Вот и весь скрипт :)

Получилось что-то типа:

[image]

Comment: Вообще-то меня интересует сам скрипт, а не результат его отработки. Если не найду, придется самому писать что-то наподобие.